# how to switch between html source View and web view IN UIwebview IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uiwebview

I'm creating html editor in IOS using UIwebview but I want to ask how to make the UIwebview switch between the html sources code view  and web view can someone show me how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UIWebView` does not support switching between preview and source modes. You should probably look at something like a custom `UITextView` to view and edit the HTML source.

Comment: This, and write the contents of the textView to a file with an HTML extension, then browse to it with a UIWebView